# Sum table1 Between $date1 and $date2 AND username Equals $user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sum

hello im having some problem with this sum select does anyone know whats wrong with this, it seems that im getting no result from it

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(total)   
FROM table1 where   date BETWEEN '".$date1." 00:00:00' AND '".$date2." 23:59:59' and  username = ".$user."");  
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{  $sum = $row['SUM(total)'];}
```

Comment: Add sample data, what you are trying to accomplish with query and desired output

Comment: (1) give your SUM(total) an alias -> SUM(total) as totalSum, (2) quote your username -> username = '".$user."',  and (3) select your column alias -> $sum = $row['totalSum']

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(total) AS result   
          FROM table1 
          WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2' 
          AND username = '$user'"; 

$con = \\your db connection string
$result = mysql_query($con,$query);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{$sum = $row['result'];}
```

Comment: @user3441486: Was this helpful ?